# teleporting players to ender pearls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm just messing around with 1.13 command blocks, trying to figure them out. I cannot use functions as I don't have access to the world files, and also I felt more comfortable using command blocks.

Anyway, I'm trying to make ender pearls that carry you with then as they fly (like on Hypixel server), so I've placed two repat command blocks, with these commands:

```
execute at @e[type=minecraft:ender_pearl] run team join pearl @p
```

and:

```
team join pearl2 @e[type=minecraft:ender_pearl]
```

and they work fine. however, when I try to teleport the the entities together, I get nothing. I'm using this command in the final repeat command block:

```
execute at @e[team=pearl2] run tp @e[team=pearl] ~ ~ ~
```

Any help or advice on the new command system would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just do `/tp @e[team=pearl] @e[team=pearl2]` instead of that execute command?

Comment: Also, I don't think this approach is multiplayer friendly, if that is of any concern to you.

Comment: I just removed [minecraft-redstone] from (almost) all [minecraft-commands] questions and here's another one! Why do people keep thinking they have to add the redstone tag to commands questions? You shouldn't even use redstone in command contraptions and even if you do, it's not the point of the question! The redstone tag even says not to use it together!

Comment: Sorry that you happened to be the one to receive my anger, it just keeps happening, I don't know why and you were the first one to do it after I cleaned up the tag. I've edited the tag wiki now, I hope that helps.

Comment: By 'fly', you mean when they're thrown, right?

Comment: @D-Inventor, I didn't use the first command because then the player hits the pearl and stops it mid-air,

Comment: and  @Fabian Röling, I just put the tag because it had "minecraft" in it. sorry 'bout that.

Comment: There are 36 "minecraft" tags, you can only use 5 tags in total. ;)

Comment: @4AC11 have you tried teleporting the player to a location above the Ender Pearl?

Comment: @54D thats kind of like a minor tweak to be honest. the problem is that the command doesn't do ANYHING whatsoever. however, I will be sure to try thst on the final product.

Answer (score 1):

Something you can do is:
A repeating command block, set to unconditional, always active, and with this command:

```
/execute at @e[type=minecraft:ender_pearl] run tp @p ~ ~ ~
```

Then have a chain command block run:

```
/execute at @e[type=minecraft:ender_pearl] run effect give @p resistance 2 255 true
```

I believe it is multiplayer friendly.
Make sure to type this command: `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false`, unless you want to have your chat spammed with tp messages.